# Flickr Integration using Cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, flickr

I am using FlickrKit to attempt to login to my Flickr account in my iOS Application.

And, I have added the following to my Project `[[FlickrKit sharedFlickrKit] initializeWithAPIKey:]` - Flickr Key - Flickr Secret

Then I called `[[FlickrKit sharedFlickrKit] beginAuthWithCallbackURL:]` - where the callback URL is `@"flickrkit://auth"`

Unfortunately after the logging in process, I got this error when I try to login using FlickrKit.

> OOPS an error has occurred.
>
> An external application has asked to link to your Flickr account, but failed to include all the necessary information. Specifically:

(then I see a black bar, so I have no idea what the specific error is).

I did all the steps as mentioned by this link:

[Flickr Github](https://github.com/devedup/FlickrKit)